# quiero pasar un archivo a zip en js y no me funciona

Tags: javascript, jszip

yo tengo una carpeta con los archivos que tengo que convertir para que sea una sola carpeta y los traigo al componente para convertirlos y hacer un button con un onclick para que me descargue el zip

```
const exportarzip=(Jar)=>{
    
    // const {arrayarchivos}=files;
    
        
        zip.file({base64: true},Jar);
    
    zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(function(content){
        saveAs(content,"sendcodojo.zip");
    });
    zip=require('jszip');
 }
```

Comment: "No me funciona" qué significa? QUé sale en la consola del navegador? Qué comportamiento tiene el botón o la página o el navegador cuando hacer lo que intentas hacer? Considera ir a [edit] y añadir la info faltante

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que si lo estás haciendo en nodejs para instanciarla debes colocar de primero y declarando como variable (var) de esta forma  `var zip = require('jszip');` si lo vas a hacer tradicional sería con `var zip = new JSZip();` el código sería así:

```
const exportarzip=(Jar)=>{
    
    // const {arrayarchivos}=files;
    
      //Tradicional 
      var zip = new JSZip();
        
      //con  NodeJs
      var zip = require("jszip");

        zip.file({base64: true},Jar);
    
    zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(function(content){
        saveAs(content,"sendcodojo.zip");
    });
 }
```

IMPORTANTE: Solo utiliza una manera de instanciarla.

De igual forma te dejo la documentación aquí-> https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html